# JavaScript Sinusbot PostgreSQL\ error: pq: value too long for type character(1)

Tags: javascript, postgresql

I have a problem with my script: **error: pq: value too long for type character(1)**

My table is built like this:

```
    CREATE TABLE ip_logs (
      ip_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
      nickname TEXT NOT NULL, 
      ip_adress TEXT NOT NULL);
```

My script:

```
    dbc.exec("INSERT INTO ip_logs(ip_id, nickname, ip_adress) VALUES ((SELECT max(ip_id)+1 FROM ip_logs), ?, ?)", nick, ip);
```

and

```
    dbc.exec("INSERT INTO ip_logs(ip_id, nickname, ip_adress) VALUES ('20', 'test', 'test')");
```

dbc is implemented like this:

```
var dbc = db.connect({ driver: 'postgres', host: ip_db, username: login_db, password: password_db, database: 'ip_log' }...
```

The second script works properly in psql console.
I searched in google but i didnt get a helpful informations.

SinusBot 1.0.0-beta.10-202ee4d

Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS

[psql console view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsRIu.png)

Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/YjX3FHrS

[Edit 1]
I tried:

`dbc.exec("INSERT INTO ip_logs(ip_id, nickname, ip_adress) VALUES (20, 'test', 'test')");`

It gives me the same error :/

[Edit 2]

I used this:
`dbc.exec("INSERT INTO ip_logs(ip_id) VALUES (20)");` and modified table - now it is without NOT NULL parameter and it works properly. What's the problem to insert other data?

[Edit 3]
I didnt get a solution, but I closed this thread, cuz I found another problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't do this:

```
dbc.exec("INSERT INTO ip_logs(ip_id, nickname, ip_adress)
VALUES ((SELECT max(ip_id)+1 FROM ip_logs), ?, ?)", nick, ip);
```

Never compute the next id like that. It's not scalable and can lead to race conditions. Use a sequence instead.

2. This failed

```
dbc.exec("INSERT INTO ip_logs(ip_id, nickname, ip_adress) VALUES ('20', 'test', 'test')");
```

probably because the `ip_id` is an integer, so this should work:

```
dbc.exec("INSERT INTO ip_logs(ip_id, nickname, ip_adress) VALUES (20, 'test', 'test')");
```

Comment: With psql console my version works properly, I will add ss to the main thread. I checked multiple solutions and I didnt find :( For sure I will check ur code and I will give u feedback.

Comment: I changed to your code and I still have the same error :(

Comment: @Zarezerwowany Are you sure that you're using PostgreSQL and that the table was defined as written above?

Comment: Yes, Im sure. I dropped the table and script called an error about no table is there, and then i created a new table and the same error occured. Sorry for my english, if u dont understand just write :)

Edit 1: U can check on ss called 'psql console view' in the main thread

Comment: @Zarezerwowany How do you know what line it is that causes the error?

Comment: I think the problem is with dbc.exec, cuz I can exec it manually on the server console but script gives an error. I only found in google a problem with varying(255) and it was about sending data bigger than 255. Here it looks like the max data can be sent with 1 length (?)and I dont know thats it or not. Edit 1: It was caused cuz they used 'char' instead of 'text'

Comment: It doesn't seem related to this table+insert statements. Are there any other SQL statements in your script.

Comment: All other statements are commented. I can give u all the script on pastebin
Edit 1: https://pastebin.com/YjX3FHrS

Comment: I used this: dbc.exec("INSERT INTO ip_logs(ip_id) VALUES (20)");
I changed the table - now its without NOT NULL and it inserted data properly.

Comment: I found a thing: I can insert data of 2 chars, but 3 gives this error. Have u any idea about that?
dbc.exec("INSERT INTO ip_logs(ip_id, nickname) VALUES (126, 'abc')"); error, dbc.exec("INSERT INTO ip_logs(ip_id, nickname) VALUES (126, 'ab')"); ok